# Fixed points of $\dot{x}=k+x-x^3$

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

Consider $\dot{x}=k+x-x^3$, with $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

It is clear that the system has $1$ fixed point if $k>0.3849$ (approximately) and if $k<-0.3849$.

If $-0.3849<r<0.3849$, the system has $3$ fixed points.

Visually, the parametric solution looks like

[image]

> How can we see this analytically? Is there a nice way to solve
>   $k+x-x^3=0$ explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the extrema of the function $f(x) = k + x - x^3$ in $x$, to give you the points at which the number of fixed points can vary.  So, differentiate and set that equal to zero, $f'(x) = 1-3x^2$, so $x = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and $f(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) = \pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9} \approx0.3849002...$

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can use [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) for an explicit solution to the general depressed cubic

$$
t^3 + p t + q = 0 \, .
$$